# How Can I convert a Map of (Key1=Value1,Key2=Value2) into a Map of (Value1=Valu2) in Apex?

Tags: apex

I have `Map<String, Object> results = {Id=10001,Value=7777},`

I want a `map` with `{10001=7777}` type.

This is what I attempted :-

```
Map<String,String> TraversedResultMap = new Map<String,String>();             
for (String s : results.KeySet()) {           
    TraversedResultMap.put(String.valueOf((String)results.get(s)),String.valueOf((String)results.get(s)));
}
system.debug('###TRAVERSED RESULT'+TraversedResultMap);
```

But I'm getting o/p as : `{10001=10001,7777=7777}`

Answer (score 0):

You're not inserting key as a value in your `for` loop. That's why you're getting same key-value pair.

See below code:

```
Map<String,String> TraversedResultMap = new Map<String,String>();             
for (String s : results.KeySet()) {           
    // here key: String.valueOf((String)results.get(s))
    // and Value: s
    TraversedResultMap.put(String.valueOf((String)results.get(s)),s);
}
system.debug('###TRAVERSED RESULT'+TraversedResultMap);
```